# A ordem de importação de componentes interfere na performance?

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, react

Hoje me perguntei sobre uma questão na ordem de importação de componentes, seja isso no Angular, React, ou Vue.

A ordem de importação de componentes referente a ordem de uso, melhoraria a performance ou nada a ver? Onde tudo esta já esta buildado e o js só se encarregará exibir o conteúdo.

Comment: Possivelmente em alguns casos.

Answer (score 2):

No React não faz diferença a ordem de importação. 
Existe uma extensão no VSCode chamda "Import Cost" que mostra o peso(tamanho) que tem sua importação, assim você pode analisar se deveria importar tudo daquele componente ou somente o que vai usar.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usa simplesmente `require`, o webpack compila todos os seus módulos para um único arquivo javascript, e de acordo com o tamanho dos módulos (+ dependências) esse arquivo será grande. Então se for uma aplicação web e o usuário estiver numa internet lenta logicamente a aplicação deve demorar um pouco para iniciar pela primeira vez.

Para resolver isso o o webpack possui o recurso de Code Spitting (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) onde quando você usa a função `import()` ele divide seus módulos em pequenos arquivos que são carregados somente quando necessário. Dessa maneira o seu build fica menor, logo a sua aplicação inicia mais rapidamente.

No caso do Vue.js existe os Componentes Dinâmicos e Assíncronos (https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html).